# activate soft wrap (at preferred line length) for specific file types only?

Tags: atom-editor

I want the regular soft wrap to be turned on by default for every file type, but I also want to apply a preferred line length for a specific file type only. I need to work with regular .txt files sometimes and it would be a big help if I could have **soft wrap at preferred line length (80)** automatically enabled for **.txt files only**. Is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can override the global soft wrap settings in a package's settings:

1. Open your Atom settings
2. Click on Installed Packages
3. Search for `language-text` and click on the package
4. Edit the soft wrap settings

[image]

If you feel at home editing your `config.cson`, here's a *minimum example* that reflects this setting:

```
"*":
  editor: {}
".plain.text":
  editor:
    softWrap: true
    softWrapAtPreferredLineLength: true
```

Comment: Sweet, worked like a charm! Thanks.